# KDE Widget not loading- Netspeed widget

Tags: kubuntu, kde, ubuntu-sdk, qml

This is the error i'm facing...

```
Error loading QML file: 
file:///home/conman/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.netspeedWidget/contents/ui/main.qml:45:37: Type CompactRepresentation unavailable

file:///home/conman/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.netspeedWidget/contents/ui/CompactRepresentation.qml:20:1: module "org.kde.plasma.private.quicklaunch" is not installed
```

I tried reinstalling but still this error continues...

I'm currently on kubuntu 20.04
This worked properly untill yesterday...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the command you ran that generated the output.

Comment: hey @DKBose, I haven't used any command to display this ... the error generates when I add this widget to the desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do re-install this package: `sudo apt-get install plasma-widgets-addons`